# How do you exit a terminal buffer unless in a pager

Tags: terminal-buffer, pager

In a terminal buffer, I want to auto-exit when I press "kk". Except for when I'm in some interactive session, like a pager (like the pager which is created when you `git diff`).

To do that, I have this code

```
let g:_pager_bottom_texts = [":", "?", "/", "Pattern not found  (press RETURN)", "(END)"]



function! MoveIfNotInPager()
    let l:current_line = getline(".")

    if index(g:_pager_bottom_texts, l:current_line) >= 0
        normal i
        call timer_start(0, {-> feedkeys("k")})
    endif
endfunction


tnoremap kk <C-\><C-n>:call MoveIfNotInPager()<CR>
```

And it works moderately well, actually. I've noticed though that, in a pager, pressing `k` is about 1/2 speed compared to `j` when I'm in a terminal buffer. Can anyone recommend a better way which still gets what I'm looking for without causing terminal or pager experience to be slower?

Comment: Isn't this just a matter of conflicting mapped keys? If you change to, say, `<leader>k` instead of `kk` does the problem go away?

Comment: No, it's definitely not a conflicting mapping issue. You can reproduce the slowness by changing `kk` to anything (`<leader>k` like you suggested, `pp`, or literally anything). Now open a pager and observe how it's slower to scroll up than it is to scroll down with `j`. I'm not really sure what exactly causes the slowness. But it's probably because the `timer_start` line isn't as efficient as it could be.

Comment: Okay. I had to ask..."1/2 speed" was ambiguous and thus that choice of keys suggested something along those lines. You might want to clarify that it refers to scroll speed in the question itself.

Comment: Why a timer? What about term_sendkeys?

Comment: Actually, your question title doesn’t match with the body. The title talks about exiting, the code doesn’t do it, and the question in the body is about the slower key-presses. Can you clarify by [edit]ing what exactly it is your question is?

Comment: I tried substituting the timer_start line with `call term_sendkeys(bufnr(), "k")`. Unfortunately, it was just as slow.

Comment: >  The title talks about exiting, the code doesn’t do it


The code does exit. That's what `<C-\><C-n>` does. I press `kk` (or `pp` or w/e), it exits the terminal buffer in order to run `MoveIfNotInPager`. And `MoveIfNotInPager` determines whether to re-enter the terminal, which it does not do unless it is in a pager. It re-enters via `normal i`. But the mapping is slower to scroll up, even when using `pp` (which has no mapping conflicts).

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I suspect half speed is because vim waits for following keys on the first k press, as it does with all maps

Comment: We have different meanings of enter/exit a terminal. I read exit a terminal as one of (a) exit the buffer--switch to a different buffer or (b) close the terminal, possibly by sending `exit`. You're talking about changing between *terminal mode* and *(terminal) normal mode*

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a proper solution for this problem. However, if you stack two "k" calls together, the 1/2 speed becomes full speed again.

So I ended up with this

```
let g:_pager_bottom_texts = [":", "?", "/", "Pattern not found  (press RETURN)", "(END)"]


" If the user is in a pager, re-enter the terminal buffer and scroll up
function! MoveIfInPager()
    let l:current_line = getline(".")

    " re-enter the terminal buffer and press "k" to scroll up in the pager
    if index(g:_pager_bottom_texts, l:current_line) >= 0
        normal i

        " We send 2 "k" keys, so it scrolls at double-speed
        call timer_start(0, {-> feedkeys("k")})
        call timer_start(10, {-> feedkeys("k")})  " 10 happened to be a decent number
    endif
endfunction
```